# Get value from database not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, sql

I'm making an asp.net application, I'm trying to read data from sql tables, but data just wont compare, as I don't get the message "You don't have a bank account, you can't register to our website"

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHKELQIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-Banking;Integrated Security=True");

connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = null;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE Accountnumber='" + accountnumber1.Text + "'", connection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();  

if (reader.Read())
{
   string getAccountNumber = reader[0].ToString();
   reader.Close();

   if (getAccountNumber != accountnumber1.Text)
   {
      lblaccountnumber.Visible = true;
      lblaccountnumber.Text = "You don't have a bank account, you can't register to our website";
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is descriptive of your question. "This just wont work" is totally meaningless, and contains no value as a search result for future users of this site that are trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried outputting reader[0].ToString() to console and seeing what is there?

Comment: Hmmmm... Perhaps the account number is `123'; DROP TABLE ACCOUNTS;--`.  I know a guy named [Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) who has that very account number!

Comment: I've modified the title. Your problem isn't displaying a message, your problem is about reading data from the database. I realize the message is the end goal, but it's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check `reader.HasRows` property and show the message

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHKELQIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-Banking;Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE Accountnumber= @Accountnumber", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Accountnumber", accountnumber1.Text);
        connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            lblaccountnumber.Visible = true;
            lblaccountnumber.Text = "You don't have a bank account, you can't register to our website";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a million man, this worked fine, as != comparison wash't working, i just don't know why, but this worked, thanks a lot man, u helped my greatly

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find this issue is to put a break point on the line:

```
if (getAccountNumber != accountnumber1.Text)
```

and see why the values do not match.

My guess is that account number is not the first column in your `SELECT *` query, thus `reader[0].ToString()` is not really the account number, but another value. Instead get the column index via the column name, like this:

```
string getAccountNumber = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Accountnumber"));
```

---

It would also be a great idea to use a parameterized query so you do not get a visit from [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Here is your code using a parameterized query:

```
string theQuery = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE Accountnumber=@AccountNumber";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(theQuery, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountnumber1.Text);

reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: yes, but OP seems to be expecting them to not equal and thus display the message.

Comment: @ethorn10 - good point, updated answer with my new "guess" as to the issue.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, i strongly confirm that account number is the first column in my table, as when i change != to == it works perfectly, but != comparison is not working, i have never experienced a problem like this before